# In Battlefield 3 what can slowly damage my tanks?

Tags: battlefield-3

Sometimes my tank starts taking damage and I honestly cannot figure out what the heck causes it. Immediately you want to think its a Repair Tool, but it's not, because I literally get out of my tank and physically walk around it and nothing and nobody is there AND my tank keeps taking damage while I'm looking around. As well as inside the tank proximity scanning shows somebody near. The next thing I think of is a rotary wing aircraft shooting at me with it's cannon, which CAN happen but drains a tank's health much faster than what's happening to me.

This is pretty slow-- at about one or two percent per second-- and a Repair Tool is much faster, but still that's not possible, because it has to be right up against the vehicle, and the damage is different than a Repair Tool, much slower.

Sometimes this happens around enemy positions such as a flag that they are holding. Other times, I'm pretty distant from any flags when this happens. I can physically get out, look around, and even look for rotary wing or fixed wing aircraft shooting at me from a long distance. It's also not possible that a heavy caliber machine gun is doing this, because that's what I originally thought, but just today this happened and I absolutely know that nobody was shooting at me with a heavy MG, or anything else for that matter.

This truly puzzles me and I cannot figure it out. Like I said, I have literally gotten out of my vehicle a dozen times when this has started happening and searched around and can't find anybody or anything doing this, including a little EOD because this continues damaging my tank when I step out, and once its destroyed, nothing is around me.

The only remote defense is quickly moving away from the area, but that is never 100% and it usually kills me due to being damaged and slow at that point. Also this phenomenon seems to start when my tank's health is low, I was at 25% when it started happening today.

So what can be doing this slow damage to my tanks?

Comment: Does the game have any environmental hazards like fires or spikes that you might be parked on top of?

Comment: I'm not sure about Battlefield 3 in particular, but I know from Battlefield 4 and 1 that once your tank is already damaged (and maybe on fire) it keeps taking damage until you repair it or it blows up. Maybe its the same thing?

Comment: You are correct @XN16 I finally got two answers that link up, and make complete sense of this whole thing. It turns out that feature is in BF3 as well, and I'm glad because I always wondered why smoking, flaming vehicles didn't take continual damage, apparently they do! so that just makes it more logical and sensible. Of course you also get out and fix the most complicated pieces of machinery in the world with nothing but a blowtorch lol but that's funny and I like it, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a normal feature of the game: when your vehicle's health is below a certain amount (depending on the vehicle, and on server parameters), it is taking damage until it reaches 0%, or until it is repaired by an Engineer.

Source: my own experience, and [this wikia page](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Disable_Vehicle).

> In Battlefield 3, vehicles that are reduced to a certain percentage of
>   health will become disabled, having compromised movement and control.
>   They also catch fire and will burn until reaching 0% health and
>   exploding, unless repaired by an Engineer or by specializations such
>   as an Extinguisher. The disabled vehicle must be fully repaired,
>   otherwise it will soon catch fire again.
>
> For most land vehicles, this threshold is at 50%, while air vehicles
>   will not catch fire until ~30% health remaining.

Comment: Thank you!! (I know it say's not to use this for thanks, but I have other stuff to say, I wish there was some feature that allowed you to say thanks, but I haven't found it yet, anyway) You are totally right, I finally got several answers on both this forum, and an Official BF3 forum that linked up, and I tested it myself and you are all correct, once it reaches a threshold it takes continual damage, which is logical and makes perfect sense, no wonder I was so confused about the contradicting evidence lol, weirdly I couldn't find that wikia page you gave me when I first searched, thanks for it

Comment: @DanielKylePrince you're welcome. could you please accept my answer as the answer you were looking for then? It will close this question, and that's the way here to recognize someone's help.

Comment: I actually don't know how to do that, I'll look around on the page but if I don't find it by the time you read this just point it out, is it the "Answer Your Question" button? I up voted your answer but because I have less than whatever amount of things it requires it doesn't show up, which kinda ticks me off considering how much time I've spent here and still don't have that 'privilege' anyway, just lemme know